# Is there a conflict between setting initial visibility and animating visibility for one element?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**EDIT: corrected a typo in the CSS noted by [ARLCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2313967/arlcode) below - not relevant.**
Using only CSS, I'm trying to animate some text, so that different blocks of text start hidden, become visible on a timer, and then fade on a timer, in sequence.

First, I start with all of the text hidden using `p {visibility: hidden}`, and add an animation to change the visibility value after *n* seconds.

In addition, I nested `<p>` in `<div>` and added an animation to fade `<div>` by animating opacity. This should fade the text that had just appeared, after (*n*+*x*) seconds.

The fade-out is no problem, but the pop-in never works. When I try to animate visibility, no matter how, the page always loads with the selected text visible, despite its earlier setting as hidden. Thus, it doesn't pop-in. It's just already there on the page. Below is the code and a link to codepen.

Am I on the wrong track?

**HTML**

```
<p id="one">this is visible on page load and then fades</p>

<div id="two-container"> <!---this div is for fading the text--->
  <p id="two">this should START hidden, then appear AFTER p one fades</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/***************************************
                GENERAL
***************************************/

p {
  visibility: hidden;
}

/***************************************
        TEXT ANIMATION SEQUENCE
***************************************/

#one {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#two {
  -webkit-animation-name: pop-in;
          animation-name: pop-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
          animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#two-container {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
          animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/***************************************
                ANIMATION KEYFRAMES
***************************************/

@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  0%, 50% {opacity: 1; }
  100% {opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pop-in {
  0% {visibility: hidden; }
  100% {visibility: visible; }
}
```

[**Code Pen Demo**](http://codepen.io/jfphilosophy/full/pJEpzQ/)

You can see in the preview that the page loads #two as visible, despite `p {visibility:hidden;}` in the general section. Removing the pop-in animation fixes this. The fade-out animation for #two-container works fine. What am I missing?

**A point of clarity: I do NOT expect - as many others here have - for visibility to animate as a fade. I want the desired text to *appear* suddenly, and AFTERWARDS fade gradually - thus the second animation selecting `<div>`. The binary nature of visibility is fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here you go I think this is the effect you want.

**CSS**

```
#one {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
          animation-duration: 5s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#two {
  visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: pop-in 2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
       -moz-animation: pop-in 2s;
        -ms-animation: pop-in 2s; 
         -o-animation: pop-in 2s; 
          animation: pop-in 2s; 
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  from {opacity: 1; }
  to {opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pop-in {
0% { visibility: visible; opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); }
100% { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
@-moz-keyframes pop-in {
0% { visibility: visible; opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(0.5); }
100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}
@keyframes pop-in {
0% { visibility: visible; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.5); }
100% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1); }
}
```

**[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wazpPY)**

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to use `p {opacity}` to bring `<p>` in first. Any idea why `visibility` is so uncooperative with this effect?

Comment: Hm, what are you exactly trying to do? Did you want it to move up and take the place of the first p?

Comment: No I just wanted it to be invisible until I called it, and then to have it fade when I finished with it. The intended effect, with background transitions, is like a CSS slideshow with text.

I just don't understand why, when I give <p> a time animation to become visible, it becomes visible immediately on page load, even though it's set to `hidden` first. Even if CSS cascades, seeing the animation property to "become visible" first, the timer should keep that from happening until several second after loading the page, right?

Comment: Well, if you notice how I rewrote the code. I have `Visibility: hidden` first then when the animation is taking place I enable the visibility with `Visibility: visible`. You have to remember when dealing with any code if you want something to start a certain way it must be defined as such. So, if you want it to start hidden then you should have the default value as hidden. If it isn't defined the browser will assume the text is visible. Could you imagine if it was the other way around? If computers defaulted to hidden? We would have to justify everything as visible.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you placed `-webkit-` as `--webkit-` I fixed the CSS down below.

**CSS**

```
#one {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#two {
  -webkit-animation-name: pop-in;
          animation-name: pop-in;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
          animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#two-container {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
          animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
          animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  0%, 50% {opacity: 1; }
  100% {opacity: 0; }
}
```

**[Code Pen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wazpPY)**

Comment: I remember when I first started programming in Python. I spent hours and hours just to find out Python uses tabs instead of brackets. I'm just glad I could help. :)

Comment: The original problem is that I want to have all text start hidden, and appear on animation timers, but when I set up timers the text cannot be set to hidden at the start.

Comment: I see what you are referring to now, fixing it.

Comment: The malfunctioning animation -webkit-animation-name: pop-in; doesn't have the typo, and the correction doesn't address the problem. You can see that the page still loads the second <p> visible in your codepen demo, despite the initial visibility value set to hidden